# Node: Callback is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to check if password given by user is correct. Login details are located in Customers-table in MySQL database. Here is my Node code:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var loginCredentials = {
    Email: req.body.email,
    Password: req.body.password,
  }
  console.log(loginCredentials);

  function CheckPassword(loginCredentials) {
    con.query("SELECT Password FROM Customers WHERE Email =?", loginCredentials.Email, function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        callback(null, result);
      } else {
        callback(true, err);
      }
    })
  }
  if (loginCredentials.Password == CheckPassword(loginCredentials)) {
    res.send("Login successfull");
  } else {
    res.send("Login failed: incorrect password");
  }
});
```

No matter what I try, my function `CheckPassword()` is returning `undefined`. I tried to fix that using callbacks but now my application crashes with `Reference Error: callback is not defined`

Could I have some advise on the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `callback(null, result)`. Where do you define `callback`?

Comment: `CheckPassword` doesn't return anything, what do you think you're comparing with in `loginCredentials.Password == CheckPassword(loginCredentials)`?

Comment: @Barmar I don't technically need callback, I need my database query to wait for result. I tried to do that with callbacks but it does not work. I have also tried without function CheckPassword (running the code directly after app.post) but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to compare with variable result.

Comment: As @Barmar write: You try to call callback() function, where do you define this function, what does this function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`callback` should be a parameter to `checkPassword()`. It can then compare the password in `result` with the entered password.

Note that you should *not* store plaintext passwords in the database in a real application. The password should be salted and hashed, and you compare the hashed passwords.

```js
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var loginCredentials = {
    Email: req.body.email,
    Password: req.body.password,
  }
  console.log(loginCredentials);
  CheckPassword(loginCredentials, returnResult);

  function CheckPassword(loginCredentials, callback) {
    con.query("SELECT Password FROM Customers WHERE Email =?", loginCredentials.Email, function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        callback(false, result);
      } else {
        callback(true, err);
      }
    })
  }

  function returnResult(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      res.send(`Database error: ${result}`);
    } else {
      if (result.length > 0 && loginCredentials.Password == result[0].Password) {
        res.send("Login successfull");
      } else {
        res.send("Login failed: incorrect email or password");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Says CheckPassword is not defined. I assume it should be declared above app.post?

Comment: I didn't get the case of `C` correct. camelCase doesn't usually capitalize the first word.

Comment: Apparently you are a genius, it works :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Allow your `CheckPassword` function to take a callback. You can then pass that callback on directly to `con.query`. Invoke `CheckPassword` and make your check and send a response in the callback:

```
function CheckPassword(loginCredentials, callback) {
  con.query(
    "SELECT Password FROM Customers WHERE Email =?",
    loginCredentials.Email,
    callback
  );
}

app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
  var loginCredentials = {
    Email: req.body.email,
    Password: req.body.password,
  };

  CheckPassword(loginCredentials, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send("Login failed: incorrect password");
    } else {
      res.send("Login successfull");
    }
  });
});
```

Note: there really seems like no need to redefine `CheckPassword` for each request, so I've moved it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `callback` for this. The callback you calling doesn't exists. That `callback` should exist as a function argument of `CheckPassword(...)` and you only have `loginCredentials`.

I think you just need to return the correct result inside the callback of `con.query`.